# Vue won't render anything if there are *any* errors

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning Vue, and I notice that when other people view their webpages, it mostly displays alright even if they haven't finished the code. This is the behavior I'm used to from vanilla html/css/javascript.

But every time I have *any* problem with a component, e.g. undefined variable, it breaks the whole component and nothing gets displayed. For example, in a Single File Component if I have

```
<template>
  <form>
    <label>Write the title:</label>
    <input v-model="title"></input>

    /* Bunch of other stuff */
    
  <form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
       /* I forget to write title here */
     }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

The whole template won't get displayed. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? It makes development much harder.

Btw I'm using Vue CLI 3 and used Vue UI to create the project, and "npm run serve" to view the site.

Comment: You need to define the `title` property in data before using `v-model`

Comment: I know, but in the tutorial I'm following (VueMastery), they add the template code before filling in the script section, and it displays fine on the webpage, even if the logic is broken. (Just like how vanilla html elements will display even if the vanilla JS is broken). Is this how it's supposed to work, or is the template just not supposed to load, like I experience?

Comment: Hi @Paradox, Correct - Virtual DOM preparation gets controlled during `created` hook and when `JS` doesn't find the related dependency of `title` and it's getting used without any check then It will break that module and stop the DOM preparation. If `Vuemastery` shows it then u can raise but it's expected to get broken if there's no check